# Amazon S3 API : List and Get "Folder" contents

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I know and I used the s3Client.listObjects (req) method with ListObjectsRequest. It works perfectly. You create an object:

```
ListObjectsRequest ()
    .withBucketName (bucket)
    .withPrefix (folderPath)
    .withDelimiter (DELIMITER)
```

These in some cases where you have simulated a folder structure is very useful **TO GET A SUMMARY.**

There is some way to use the same logic of prefixes and delimiters **to get the full objects instead of summary** This can be useful when you want to obtain a few limited objects.

The alternative is to launch a list and "n" gets, but I want to know if there is any way to launch a single call (a single http call),

something like:

```
GetObjectsRequest ()
           .withBucketName (bucket)
           .withPrefix (folderPath)
           .withDelimiter (DELIMITER)
```

and that it returns the complete objects ... (or a **paged list**)

Comment: To clarify: *"the complete objects"* means the *entire* body and metadata for all the listed objects?

Comment: Yes, the full object, as you get it , with the "get" method.

Answer (score 2):

There is no capability for this in the underlying [S3 API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html).  Objects have to be fetched individually.  The only action that comes to mind would that operates on multiple objects within the context of a single API action is [multi-object delete](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/multiobjectdeleteapi.html).

Any given S3 bucket can, of course, handle a very large number of concurrent `GET` requests, so you could get all the objects in a short amount of time if you take advantage of whatever asynchronous and/or multi-threading capabilities your language of choice offers.

If the object bodies are very small, you could also encapsulate this in a Lambda function that would do all the work and package everything up, keeping your calling code tidier.  But Lambda functions have a [payload limit of 6MB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) for request and response... so the objects would need to be small, for that approach to work.

Comment: I think it would be desirable if the results of the listings (S03SummaryItem) return something more than the key (the owner and little else). At a minimum, customized metadata .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885059/amazon-s3-listing-object-with-metadata-in-single-request

Comment: I see that there is a great demand for this utility from the users of the API for a long time and it has not evolved)))) (