# how to get Object URL and Server-side encryption while returning S3ObjectSummary

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have created a java service to return the meta-data of the S3 objects but in my json response it's not returning the Server-side encryption and Object URL

Here is my code

```
 @GetMapping(value = "/ListS3BucketsObjects")
    public List<S3ObjectSummary> ListS3BucketsObjects(@RequestParam String bucketName) {
        try {
            BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials("xxxx",
                    "xxxxxxx");
            final AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))
                    .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
            ObjectListing objectListing = s3client.listObjects(bucketName);
            return objectListing.getObjectSummaries();
        } catch (Exception Ex) {
            throw Ex;
        }
    }
```

I'm getting result like this

```
[
    {
        "bucketName": "xxxx",
        "key": "xx",
        "size": 489583,
        "lastModified": "2020-01-01T06:59:52.000+0000",
        "storageClass": "STANDARD",
        "owner": {
            "displayName": "xxxxx",
            "id": "xxx"
        },
        "etag": "xxxxx"
    }]
```

how to get the Object URL and Server-side encryption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24902974/11733759).
Based `S3ObjectSummary` you can retrieve metadata:

```java
ObjectMetadata objectMetadata = s3client.getObjectMetadata(bucketName, objectSummary.getKey());
```

Comment: pick URL alone   **S3client.getUrl(BucketName, Key).toString();**